# How to margin image without affecting the h1 and p tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the video downwards such that it align with the h1 tag. I have tried using margin-top on the image, but the h1 tags also move downward together.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section img
{
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
}
.section h1
{
  color: crimson;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.section p 
{
  color: crimson;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.video
{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="section">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>This is heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non
      excepturi rerum explicabo consequatur provident modi nesciunt officia
      corrupti at, sed tempore eligendi, praesentium ad. Deserunt
      praesentium similique ad nesciunt tempore omnis, id quisquam. In
      repellat vel, perspiciatis eaque fuga dolor ut commodi recusandae quo
      laborum consectetur cupiditate nulla repudiandae voluptas?
    </p>
  </div>
  <iframe
    width="560"
    height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gC_M-qUW-So"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen
  ></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What image? There is no `img` tag in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*align-items: flex-start; and remove H1 margin top*

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.section
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 60%;
  margin:60px auto;
}
.section img
{
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
}
.section h1 {
    color: crimson;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.section p 
{
  color: crimson;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.video
{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="section">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>This is heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non
      excepturi rerum explicabo consequatur provident modi nesciunt officia
      corrupti at, sed tempore eligendi, praesentium ad. Deserunt
      praesentium similique ad nesciunt tempore omnis, id quisquam. In
      repellat vel, perspiciatis eaque fuga dolor ut commodi recusandae quo
      laborum consectetur cupiditate nulla repudiandae voluptas?
    </p>
  </div>
  <iframe
    width="560"
    height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gC_M-qUW-So"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen
  ></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```